# How do I use Select2's tokenizer with Ajax results?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 field that uses an Ajax call to retrieve data from a remote source. I would like to be able to paste a list into the field to match results.

I have tried the following `tokenizer` method:

```
tokenizer: function (input, selection, callback) {
    var parts,
        part,
        matched = [],
        i,
        j;

    // replace whitespace with commas
    input = input.replace(/[\s]+/g, ',');
    // no comma no need to tokenize
    if (input.indexOf(',') < 0) {
        return;
    }
    parts = input.split(/[\,]+/g);
    for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
        part = parts[i];
        part = part.trim();

        // check for duplicates 
        if (matched.indexOf(part) > -1) {
            continue;
        }

        // check if the part matches
        for (j = 0; j < tagList.length; j += 1) {
            if (part === tagList[j].id) {
                matched.push(part);
                callback({id: part, text: part});
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the following Ajax results method:

```
// yes, the results are being returned properly
results: function (data) {
    var results = [],
        len = data.length,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        if (data[i].extra && data[i].extra.isp_id) {
            results.push({text: data[i].name, id: data[i].value, ispId: data[i].extra.isp_id, ispName: data[i].extra.isp_name});
        } else {
            results.push({text: data[i].name, id: data[i].value});
        }
    }
    tagList = results; // obviously, tagList is declared in a scope accessible to the tokenizer method
    return {results: results};
}
```

As you can expect, `tagList` is empty. I'm just not sure how to run the `tokenizer` method against the result data.  (1) Is this possible?  And if so, (2) how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use ajax then you should tokenize on the server-side.

Comment: This does, indeed, provide the answer. The tokenizer function is meant to tokenize items when client-side options are used. The question author is using the ajax option, meaning he is providing options via the serverside; as such tokenizer does not make sense in this context.

Comment: In other words, if I don't have access to the server being queried in order to tokenize items there, I can't paste a list of possible matches into select2?

Comment: you can, but not by using the built-in ajax helper. if you write your own query function then you can tokenize the input and issue an ajax request per token to the server to resolve the server-side item.